# How can I create a schedule that fires every nth week using simple schedule?

Tags: c#, .net, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

How can I create a schedule that fires every nth week, using quartz.net simple schedule?

Comment: What you have tried so far?????????

Answer (score 0):

Well something Like this would do the trick

```
  IScheduler sched;
private void ConfigureScheduler()
{
 int nbweeks = 1;
 int n = 24*7*nbweeks;
 var schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();
 sched = schedFact.GetScheduler();
 var job = new JobDetailImpl("weeklyjob", null, typeof(Type));
 var timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("W. Europe Standard Time");
 var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                             .StartNow()
                             .WithSimpleSchedule(x=>x.RepeatForever().WithIntervalInHours(n))
                             .Build();

 sched.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
 sched.Start();
}
```

just change nbweeks according to your needs and it will run every n week

this solution will fire once each month on the 14th day (2nd week) you can change the day of the second week as you please

```
IScheduler schedd;
private void ConfigureScheduler()
{
    var schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();

    schedd = schedFact.GetScheduler();
    var job = new JobDetailImpl("weeklyJob", null, typeof(Type));
    var timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
    var cronScheduleBuilder = CronScheduleBuilder.MonthlyOnDayAndHourAndMinute(14, 12, 0);
    var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                                .StartNow()
                                .WithSchedule(cronScheduleBuilder)
                                .Build();

    sched.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
    sched.Start();
}
```

**update**
This code will fire each second Monday of each month

```
 IScheduler schedd;
private void ConfigureScheduler()
{
    var schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();

    schedd = schedFact.GetScheduler();
    var job = new JobDetailImpl("weeklyJob", null, typeof(Type));
    var timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
    var cronScheduleBuilder = CronScheduleBuilder.CronSchedule("0 0 12 ? 1/1 MON#2 *");
    var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                                .StartNow()
                                .WithSchedule(cronScheduleBuilder)
                                .Build();

    sched.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
    sched.Start();
}
```

Comment: this is interval in hours. How can I run it every nth week?

Comment: you have  n=24*7(24 hours a day, 7 days a week this won't change for sure) by multiplying n*nthweek you will get what you want , I have been using this solution for its simplicity with hours , days and weeks

Comment: This will fire every 2 weeks right? not the 2nd week of every month. I need the expression for every 2nd week of every month. Please help

Comment: is there a way to specifically fire on specific days of the 2nd week?

Comment: Check out My last update for this subject,, just use the information  i gave to do what you want